# Change HBase WAL location

Tags: hadoop, hbase, wal

I'm planning to use HBase with gs:// scheme (google buckets), but gs:// fs can't work with WAL files.

```
Cause:
java.io.IOException: cannot get log writer
Caused by: java.io.IOException: createNonRecursive unsupported for this filesystem class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
```

As I found it should way to store WAL files separate from a HBase root dir, eg: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/images/hbase_s3.png

So, my question is - how to separate data files and WAL files. To store data in gs:// and WALs in hdfs:// ... Unfortunately still can't find it by myself ...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Current stable version doesn't support storing WALs in a different location outside of hbase.rootdir. 
It's planned in future releases, ref https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-17437